# Passing list to javascript to pass back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and my model has a list as part of it. I want to pass that list to a javascript function and inside this function I turn around and want to pass it back to a controller.

Currently I have:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Data", new { onclick = string.Format("EditRecord({0});", Model.Types) })
```

Model.Types is defined as List

My javascript EditRecord is defined as:

```
function EditRecord(types)
{
   $.post("/Data/Edit/" { myTypes: types });
}
```

My controller is define as:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string[] myTypes)
{
   return View();
}
```

When I run this I get page can't be found. If I switch this from the list to just a normal data type like an int or string then it all works, so something with the fact that it's an array is throwing this off. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes my solution, Lets say you have a model holding List property in following way -

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<string> Types { get; set; }
}
```

This model will be constructed in the following controller action and will be returned to the View -

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        model.Types = new List<string>();
        model.Types.Add("Admin");
        model.Types.Add("User");
        model.Types.Add("SuperAdmin");

        return View(model);
    }
```

And the View has following Html -

```
@model Rami.Vemula.Dev.Mvc.Controllers.MyModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row">
    <a href="#" id="ClickMe">Click me</a>
</div>
```

Now the JQuery part which will hold the logic to send the List to the controller action -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ClickMe").click(function () {
            var o = new Object();
            o.Types = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Types));

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetJson")",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(o),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                failure: function (errMsg) { alert(errMsg); }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then on clicking the button, it will hit the following controller -

```
    public JsonResult GetJson(List<string> Types)
    {
        return Json(Types, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When you click the button, and put a breakpoint to check the values -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By this your controller is returning blank view. Make sure that your view is created (right click-go to view). And if you want to return it it should be something like this:

rerurn View(myTypes);

But make sure that myTypes view is set up to accept string[].

if you want to pass your list to client consider ajax call that will send json object array and adjust your backend to accept it.